# tengo problemas con el adaptador de RecyclerView

Tags: firebase, adapter

Buenas mi problema como el de muchos es el adaptador "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
"

la idea es crear un nuevo campo en Firebase DB (que esta conectado y funciona a la perfección) 
es este el único problema que poseo!

Por muchos lados he buscado y el error es el mismo, que depronto esta vació al inicializarlo pero no encuentro el modo de inicializarlo ya con información para que me cree el espacio en Firebase.... 
la gran duda mía! es por que con el ***System.curentTimeMillis()*** puedo enviar el pedido a Firebase?

Me Urge ayuda por favor muchas gracias!!

ah y por cierto 
lo he sacado del siguiente vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlQTN7vkc0c

adjunto mi código

`

public class Carrito extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference pedido;

TextView txtTotalPrecio;
Button btn_pace;

List < Order > cart = new ArrayList<>();

CartAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);

    //Init Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    pedido = database.getReference("OrdenPedido") ;

    //Init
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ListaCarrito);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    txtTotalPrecio =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    btn_pace =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_PlaceOrder);

     btn_pace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showAlertDialog();
        }
    });

    LoadListFood();
}


private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Carrito.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Ultimo Requisito");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Ingresa tu Numero de celular");

    final EditText edtPhone = new EditText(Carrito.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    edtPhone.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(edtPhone);
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            //envair a Firebase
            Request request = new Request(
                    txtTotalPrecio.getText().toString(),
                    edtPhone.getText().toString(),
                    cart
            );

            pedido.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                            .setValue(request);
            //Delete cart
            new Database(getBaseContext()).CleanToCart();
            Toast.makeText(Carrito.this, "Gracias, Pedido Realizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}


private void LoadListFood() {

    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Precio final

    int total = 0;
    for (Order order:cart)
        total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrecio()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getCantidad()));

    Locale locale = new Locale( "es", "CO");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrecio.setText(fmt.format(total));

}
```

}

`

y adjunto tambien la clase CartAdapter!

`

class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener   {

```
public TextView txt_cart_name , txt_precio;
public ImageView   img_cart_count;

private InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener inflatedOnMenuItemClickListener;

public void setTxt_cart_name(TextView txt_cart_name) {
    this.txt_cart_name = txt_cart_name;
}

public CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txt_cart_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_name);
    txt_precio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price);
    img_cart_count = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

}

public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List< Order > listData = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public CartAdapter(List< Order > listData, Context context) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View ItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout,parent,false);
    return new CartViewHolder(ItemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getCantidad(), Color.TRANSPARENT);

    holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    Locale locale = new Locale( "es", "CO");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrecio()))
            *(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getCantidad()));
    holder.txt_precio.setText(fmt.format(price));
    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductoNombre());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (listData != null)
        return listData.size();
    return 0;
}
```

}

`

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto!
era el constructor de la Clase Request!

Cuando se llama a la clase request, esta misma tiene un constructor con los elementos que se pondrán en el carrito de compras...

el constructor tenia otro campo (nombre usuario) que no estaba llamando!
por tal motivo siempre me fallaba el envío a Firebase.

Comment: Hola Diegho Riko, me alegra que encontraras una solución a tu problema. Pero te comento que esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir más detalles: ¿cuál era el problema? ¿qué cambiaste en el constructor de la clase Request? ¿o el cambio fue en la llamada al constructor? Lee sobre [answer] para más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas.